# 2D boolean matrix number of unique combinations without mirrored/rotated ones

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Given a $n \times n$ boolean matrix, it's well known that number of all possible combinations of 0s and 1s in that matrix would be $2^{n^2}$, as there are $n^2$ places which could take exactly 2 states.

But what would be the number of unique combinations in such a matrix if we'll count mirrored either on X or Y axis (or both) only once, i.e., for example, for $n = 3$,

$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$
would be treated the same as
$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$,

as we can get the second by flipping (mirroring) the first over vertical axis.

For $n = 2$, the whole list instead on ${2^2}^2 = 16$ thus becomes just 7:

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

Is there a generic formula for a given $n$ for a number of such combinations and what's their proper name in literature?

*Update:* I've calculated first 4 elements of these sequence with a naive (and pretty slow) implementation I wrote, here they go:

2, 7, 168, 16576

*Update 2:* Given a formula derived by Chas Brown, I've calculated first 20 elements of the sequence:

- 2
- 7
- 168
- 16576
- 8407040
- 17180065792
- 140737630961664
- 4611686021648613376
- 604462909825456529211392
- 316912650057058194799105933312
- 664613997892457973921852429862699008
- 5575186299632655785387471343024242610405376
- 187072209578355573530072906199130068813267662274560
- 25108406941546723055343157693068350151952214790636769902592
- 13479973333575319897333507543510482546964893936620552409330109906944
- 28948022309329048855892746252171976963572707941600844857461926957552108568576
- 248661618204893321077691124073410420050233795539817281825067792358316682810992971743232
- 8543948143683640329580086824678208458410818089430995584700159140043489957620711049150816145375232
- 1174271291386916613944740298394668513687841274454160720757610179534144421210155636265306103796184470612082688
- 645562469521727147413979793000752968582426448207305878207666044338695099746916955128980594191986349511221130087813349376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if there is a proper name in the literature, but this sounds like a job for... Burnside's lemma! Super handy for these kinds of counting problems.

Let $X$ be the set of all $n$x$n$ binary matrices, and let $G$ be the group action on $X$ with the four elements: do nothing (identity element), flip horizontal, flip vertical, and flip horizontal then flip vertical (note that the last is the same as flip vertical then flip horizontal); whose elements I'll henceforth call $\{e, h, v, hv\}$ respectively.

Burnside's lemma says that the number of distinct matrices up to the action of this group G (written as $|X/G|$) will be:

$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}|X^g| $$

where here $X^g$ is the set of elements left unchanged by $g \in G$. So in our case

$$|X/G| = (|X^e| + |X^h| + |X^v| + |X^{hv}|)/4$$

$e$ is the identity, so $|X^e|=|X|=2^{n^2}$, and from a quick look at the other possibilities I think it follows that if $n$ is even, then $n = 2k$ and

$$|X/G| = (2^{n^2} + 2^{nk} + 2^{nk} + 2^{nk})/4$$

And if $n$ is odd, then $n = 2k+1$, and

$$|X/G| = (2^{n^2} + 2^{n(k+1)} + 2^{n(k+1)} + 2^{(k+1)^2+k^2})/4$$

Comment: An excellent answer and a great insight into Burnside's lemma - that's exactly the name I was looking for! I should mention that it even solves lots of extra problems, such as "the same problem with added 90°, 180°, 270° rotations", etc. I wonder why they've omitted group theory elements from our math statistics / combinatorics course...

Comment: Thanks GreyCat, it is a pleasure to be of service! Group Theory seems to be often taught with an eye towards Galois Theory where solvability is the king (or queen?) goal; but I always found the combinatoric stuff the most interesting.